# Maven top-level exception in Android project

Tags: android, maven

I have an Android project which I want to handle with Maven. I am pretty new to Maven so every step I have another bug to solve. I need to add this is pretty huge project with a lot of libraries. 
Here is an error :

```
[

INFO] warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
[INFO] (org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
[INFO] associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
[INFO] compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
[INFO] solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
[INFO] and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
[INFO] this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
[INFO] indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[INFO] 
[INFO] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe;
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
[INFO] 
[INFO] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/inject/AbstractModule;
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

and my pom.xml, some of the libraries come from Maven Central and some of them I added localy to my Maven repo.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>r7</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>20030203.000550</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-no_aop</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>http-client-android</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>local.admobsdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>admobsdk</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>local.kicalls</groupId>
        <artifactId>kicalls</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
        <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
        <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.11</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>

                <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                <sdk>
                    <path>/Users/asd/Desktop/sdk</path>
                    <platform>14</platform>
                </sdk>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                <attachSources>false</attachSources>
                <proguard>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </proguard>

            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
```

They say on the internet, that I should add exclusion to these two classes who produce this top-level exception, but have no clue what exclusion I shoud add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have a problem with the following dependencies:

1) roboguice and guice. To resolve, I suggest you to exclude `com.google.inject:guice` from `org.roboguice:roboguice` dependencies.

2) httpmime have a dependency to httpcore. And I guess this dependency is conflicting with old httpcomponents library embedded in android os. So you can try to exclude `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore` from dependencies of `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime`

**Remark**: as an alternative to the first suggested exclusion, you can simply try to remove the `com.google.inject:guice` dependency from your pom since a newer version (3.0) will be present as a transitive dependency of `org.roboguice:roboguice`

**Tip**: you can use the command line `mvn dependency:tree` to have a good vision of all libraries and transitive dependencies of your project.

Comment: It almost solved my problem. I added exclusion to roboguice and one top-level error disappeared. But I cannot exclude httpcore from httpmime because it is used to read many files from @drawable. There must be something else producing this error. But thanks anyway, I spent a lot of hour on this.

Comment: Here is a link referencing jars including the offending class, it may help you to solve the problem : http://mavenhub.com/c/org/apache/http/annotation/notthreadsafe/jar Additionally, you can use the command line `mvn dependency:tree` to have a good vision of all libraries and transitive dependencies of your project.

Answer (score 0):

ben75 answer is correct. But there is another way to handle it. I've just added by hand all libraries to local repository and no exceptions was needed. Here is how to do this : [Installing own jar library for Maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381904/installing-own-jar-library-for-maven-dependency/18382365?noredirect=1#18382365)

Comment: be aware that this solution is not portable and works only because you didn't install a complete pom.xml with the jar in your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a very similar problem. Other found solutions didn't worked for me so I wanted to share my workaraond. My environment: Android 4.3, api 18, plugin Maven Android 3.1.1, maven 3.0.5. I continued getting:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   [INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lorg/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap;

I built commenting out other dependencies (all but those indicated by Vogel in http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildMaven/article.html), getting BUILD SUCCESS. Then I decommented the rest of my pom and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late for the answer, but I just got into the same problem. I just added this chunk in the pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and builds just nice, since the dependency was being included twice :)